# How to hibernate automatically after power goes off?

Tags: shutdown

My PC battery is not working and I am wondering if there is any way that I can hibernate my pc automatically whenever there is power outrage!
Thanks

Comment: You probably can't. Once the power goes off, the system has no power to react and go into hibernation. Unless you want to update your question (use "edit") and state that the computer can survive a short time on the faulty battery. Note you currently state "it is not working".

Comment: In most cases you can if BIOS supports it.